# cycles volume rendering 3D image texture (CT or MR dataset)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

Is it possible to render with cycles a 3D texture from discrete image data (eg. image sequence)?

Basically I'm trying to get volume rendering of medical data with cycles.

Comment: also discussed here :[Using image sequence of medical scans as volume data in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62110/11431)

Answer (score 3):

I've had success importing CT data into blender using the free 32bit version of the open source [DICOM viewer OsiriX](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/Downloads.html), free registration required *(1)*.

1. Import your data into OsiriX
2. Double click the image-sequence to open it in the 2D Viewer
3. Choose "3D Surface Rendering" from the "2D/3D" button in the middle of the toolbar
4. Select the desired level of detail and (most important) the brightness of the pixels which should be considered the "object" *(2)*
5. Use the "3D-SR Export" button in the new "Surface Rendering" window to choose your preferred output format (.rib, .vrml, .iv, .obj or .stl)

I went with .obj and it imported smoothly into blender.

*(1)* OsiriX is Mac OS X only. The site http://www.idoimaging lists free medical image viewing software for many platforms. Maybe there is one with a similar feature set…

*(2)* Maybe you have to experiment a little in finding the right values. The available presets for Skin, Bones and Metal usually work just fine, but I have to admit, that I have no medical knowledge and therefore cannot say if this would be the case with all the CT/MR data sets out there.

[image: CT scan imported into blender]

[image: CT scan rendered with cycles]

Comment: thank for the nice tutorial. Will use it as a fall-back if our data allows it. I found out that although cycles can render volume data (transfer functions and all), the volume shaders can only handle input from either a texture node or a smoke domain. Internally the smoke domain is identical to a volume dataset. Tag-line is voxel data input for cycles and that is define in the blender issue tracker but as of yet, nobody is working on it: [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/T41179)

Similar question: [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14995/voxel-data-in-cycles)

Comment: great render btw.