# Cycles Volume Scattering with Voxel Data

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

**Problem**
I am trying to visualize the electron density of some simulations. The data would consist of a file with the density of electrons at each point in space. From reading documentation I have found that the voxel data structure would be great for this kind of data and allows for multiple frames as well.

[image]

Is it possible to use voxel data or something similar to apply a material with volume scattering? Currently I cannot find a way to use this kind of data (only image textures are allowed). Resources I have looked at typically mention that it is only possible in the blender renderer.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14995/voxel-data-in-cycles

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62110/using-image-sequence-of-medical-scans-as-volume-data-in-cycles. Do you have some sample data file?

Comment: So I actually stumbled upon those posts and what was disappointing is that they only offered work arounds. It looks like the community is just waiting for a voxelnode to be implemented. My hope was that a straightforward solution would be possed. It's fair to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Support for voxels still isn't here, but [support for point clouds](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/point_density.html) has since been added. You could try using such a point cloud, but I'm not sure how well it would work for this.

Comment: It looks like the holy grail is once openvdb is fully implemented in Blender. Not ideal but I will try out point clouds.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering since there are not really any supported volume formats (as of spring 2016) supported in Blender Cycles hacks must be used. I settled on a solution that used the answer posted in a [related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62162/38363). It is important to note this solution is a general method to create 3d image from a 2d image and is gpu accelerated. I was able to use this method to create 3d volume scattering.

[image]

Here is an ugly but fully working one that I produced with the following python code to create the input image. I found this approach to also be very memory intensive as expected since each image was 200x200x200 pixels.

```
import numpy as np
import png # using pypng

n = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
array = np.zeros(n**3).reshape(n, n**2)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            array[i, j+k*n] = (np.sin(x[i]) * np.sin(x[j]) * 
np.sin(x[k]))**2 * 2**16
array = np.floor(array).astype(np.uint16)
image = png.from_array(array, 'L')
image.save('hello.png')
```

[image]