# How to externally control the look of volume material?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, shaders

The effect that I want to achive looks like this:
[image: Desired Effect]

The problem I have is with that colorful cube with controllable color gradient. The cones and planes can be ingnored. I have achived similar result using Volume Scatter and Noise Texture node but I cannot find way to replace Noise Texture Node with my input data.

[image: What I've done so far]
 It can be anything. I thought maybe 3 2D textures in some way could control the Volume look? Maybe there is a way to control it with Python script? Maybe using raw binary voxel data (which i tried and for some reason it doesn't work in Blender 2.8) or maybe totally another way to achive similar effect.

The colors adding up to white is also a little annoying but i can live with that.

It needs to work in Blender 2.8

Comment: Can that help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62110/using-image-sequence-of-medical-scans-as-volume-data-in-cycles/62141#62141

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you so much! Is there a way to set a comment as an answer?

Comment: No but you can upvote the answers you want from the link.