# How can I animate custom textures at specific clipping surface locations?

Tags: animation, workflow

I am trying to animate a CT Scan of an arm. The result should be an animation in which the arm reveals the inside as a gradient clipping motion.
At clipping point 0 I want to show frame "alpha" of the real CT slice and at clipping point 500 I want show frame "omega" of the real CT slice. Like cutting through the arm and showing each CT slice at the exact location. Any hints on how to approach this?

Edit: The direction and shape of the clipping should be freely adjustable without changing the orientation of the sequence or its content.
I would like light it with an hdri and render it with cycles.

I added two animations [here](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kZCaBLXZAEnn1zQpMFzUGWNeLkchImatiIEV) that visualize my issue.

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62110/using-image-sequence-of-medical-scans-as-volume-data-in-cycles/62141#62141

Comment: do you have a specific file format or some examples for test case?

Comment: I have an OBJ with texture of the slit scan and the image sequence in PNG RGBA. I want to light the mesh/scene with an HDRI. I am not going for the unlit vertex color or point cloud.

Comment: If you have the image sequence already, just add an image sequence node and animate it's offset input.

Comment: One problem remains at the moment: I can only cut through the object in the direction of time or as the sequence flows—in a perpendicular way. If I wanted to cut through it with a different shape it is not possible, isn't it? I should have clarified that in the beginning, sorry for that.

Comment: But where is the information about the angle? (or shape). And could you provide a link to some CT scans as concrete example?

Comment: Hi, for future reference, it is not necessary to to remark in the question the reason for an edit, the edit history provides a space for that. Leaving it in plain text in the question creates noise that is not relevant to answering your question. :)

Comment: Please edit and improve your original post to reflect what you've learned in the comments. This site is designed not just to fix your problem, but especially for others in the future that may also have a similar issue. I am going to take a deeper look into your issue once I get to my office.

Comment: I would just add at the bottom of your original post that includes what you have additionally tried to solve the problem, or realizations that you didn't quite understand to begin with. Not trying to contradict Timaroberts, I think he's saying that you don't need to describe "Why" you edited the post since there is already an input box for that when you actually edit the post itself. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I edited the original post and added two examples to visualize the circumstances.