# Can Blender be used for 3D reconstructions of CT and MRI scans?

Tags: workflow

I would like to know if Blender can be used for 3d reconstruction of CT scans and MRI scans etc.

If so, I would like to be directed to a resource that demonstrates this. 
I would like to reconstruct 3D images of various organs of the body based on radiological scans, to also illustrate certain pathologies, for educational purposes.

Comment: Thank you Ray Mairlot, for the correction.

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18418/cycles-volume-rendering-3d-image-texture-ct-or-mr-dataset?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @sazarec thank you for pointing that out and directing me accordingly.
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be what I had expected. I was thinking along the lines of what Invesalius does.