# Visualizing 3D voxel data in Blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, import, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, point-clouds

right now I'm trying to visualize my scientific 3D data in Blender 2.8. So blenders built in textures or smoke simulations do not lead to the goal.

I've read that older releases of Blender do support voxel data with the internal blender render engine. But I didn't find this for cycles or eevee.

Is there a way to plot external 3D data for volumetric rendering or is it planned to be implemented in soon releases?

Greetings
Janek

Comment: I've been craving this too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14995/822

Answer (score 2):

As of Blender 2.83 OpenVDB is now supported as a volume object.[image]