# Is there a way to Import a Houdini Generated Volume (VDB) into Blender Cycles?

Tags: volumetrics

Is there a way to Import a Houdini Generated Volume  (VDB) into Blender Cycles?

We are working on a Uni project, and we cant seem to get a VDB into blender working at all. Has anyone done this before and is able to help.

Much appreciated Guys!

Answer (score 1):

Blender can use OpenVDB for smoke cache files (there's an option in the Smoke Cache domain settings to switch between Point Cache format and OpenVDB) but I don't know much about Houdini or whether the OpenVDB format it uses is anything like compatible with Blender.

Another option would be to transform your Houdini VDB file into a format that can be used in Blender - such as an image format as used in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149696/29586) to question "Voxel Data in Cycles". There the voxel data is converted (using Python - similar to the Smoke2EXR add-on mentioned in the link in that answer (see https://baldingwizard.wixsite.com/blog/tutorial-mesh-to-volume)) into an image containing multiple slices of the volume. Maths nodes can then be used to transform from the 3D coordinates into 2D coordinates within the relevant 'slice' and this can then be rendered as a volume.

Obviously for this to work you will need to develop something to convert from Houdini VDB into multiple image slices.

Note : It would also be useful if you could supply a sample Houdini VDB file to be able to allow others to investigate how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Until recently there has not been support for OpenVDB in Blender. In Blender 2.83, that is about to be released in a matter of weeks, there will be support for importing OpenVDB files and a more general volume object type will be introduced. The alpha of 2.83 is already available for download to try.