# Volume from Image Sequence

Tags: volumetrics

Is there a way to create Volumes (Volume Object Type in blender 2.83+) from Image Sequences?

And/Or can the Volumedata be accessed/modified with python?

This would be very nice for scientific visualizations and for creating 3D-Objects from medical scans with the new *Volume to Mesh Modifier* in 2.91.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=medical+scans

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149696/29586

Comment: I am aware of these methods to get voxeldata into blender. But these methods are quite hacky or are better suited for the old BI renderer.

So my question specifically asks for a way to get Image Seqences to work with the new Volume Object Type.

Comment: There is an addon that is related to that BVTKNodes. https://bvtknodes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html . Though I've never used it.