# Is is possible to use grid volume as 3D texture?

Tags: texturing, volumetrics

I have been able to convert and import 3D MRI brain image in Blender 3.2.2 using OpenVDB format. The result is a volume grid. Now, I would like to be able to use this volume grid (in fixed world coordinates) to make the texture of a mesh in order to see slices of my MRI volume. My goal is to create a scene similar to [this one](https://brainvisa.info/anatomist-5.0/user_doc/_images/fusion_mslice_method.png) and have the possibility to animate the various planes (i.e. move them in any position).

I tried to find a solution via the creation of a shader for the mesh but failed to make the appropriate link to the volume grid values. Can anybody help me to find the right way to do that with Blender ?

Edited on august 31, 2022:

I managed to do that in old blender version using voxel data (that was years ago) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhF4tLVme2w.

But AFAIK, there is no more voxel data in Blender. I thought they could be replaced by volume grid. I created a sample volume grid and ideally I would like to create a shader that would use that cubes to color the plane. In the following figure, the mesh texture would display a square.

[image: A plane intersecting a volume grid.]

As suggested [in another post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149696/35559), I could use a 2D texture but it is a rather complex solution requirering (if I understand well) to create a new shader for each volume image geometry (voxel size, origin, etc.).

Comment: is your volume grid a mesh, a point cloud, or some form of voxel format?

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149696/35559) is possibly relevant

Comment: My volume is composed of voxels that are cubes with a numerical value between a minimum (usually representing black) and a maximum (usually white).

Comment: Thanks Robin, this post is interesting. Long ago, I used voxel data and was able to [this with Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhF4tLVme2w). But voxels data are gone. Volume grid may be a replacement but I am not sure they can be used in shaders. I will try using 2D texture but it is far less convenient than 3D because the voxels geometry is already included in volume grids.

Comment: I edited my question to take comments into account.